# identify repeated subjects in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data :

```
subject <- c("A-B10", "A101", "A-B10", "C101", "A101", "C01", "A101", "AB101", "A.B10")
idn <- c(101, 102, 104, 100, 98, 102, 90, 102, 78)
sn <- 1:9
mydata <- data.frame (sn, subject, idn)

 sn subject idn
1  1   A-B10 101
2  2    A101 102
3  3   A-B10 104
4  4    C101 100
5  5    A101  98
6  6     C01 102
7  7    A101  90
8  8   AB101 102
9  9   A.B10  78
```

I want to identify the repeated subjects in a large dataset. The results expected would be like this:

```
repeat [1]
 sn subject idn
1  1   A-B10 101
3  3   A-B10 104

repeat [2]
sn subject idn
2  2    A101 102
5  5    A101  98
7  7    A101  90
```

Edits:

```
dup <- mydata$subject[duplicated(mydata$subject)]
mydata[mydata$subject %in% dup, ]
  sn subject idn
1  1   A-B10 101
2  2    A101 102
3  3   A-B10 104
5  5    A101  98
7  7    A101  90
lapply(dup, function(x) mydata[mydata$subject == x,])
[[1]]
  sn subject idn
1  1   A-B10 101
3  3   A-B10 104

[[2]]
  sn subject idn
2  2    A101 102
5  5    A101  98
7  7    A101  90

[[3]]
  sn subject idn
2  2    A101 102
5  5    A101  98
7  7    A101  90
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example :

```
> ## dup <- mydata$subject[duplicated(mydata$subject)]
> dup <- unique(mydata$subject[duplicated(mydata$subject)]) ## sorry, edited
> mydata[mydata$subject %in% dup, ]
  sn subject idn
1  1   A-B10 101
2  2    A101 102
3  3   A-B10 104
5  5    A101  98
> lapply(dup, function(x) mydata[mydata$subject == x,])
[[1]]
  sn subject idn
1  1   A-B10 101
3  3   A-B10 104

[[2]]
  sn subject idn
2  2    A101 102
5  5    A101  98
```

Comment: "A101" is repeated three times - is not identifying all three .

Comment: @JohnC -- Element 8 in your subject vector is `"AB101"` (not `"A101"`, as it appears in your printed data.frame and as you intended it to be), so eusebe's code is working just fine on the dataset you actually provided. Cheers.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien O'Brien I am not talking about 2, 5 and 7, not 8

Comment: @JohnC -- Fine -- a minor error on my part, but do take a moment to paste in the first four lines of code you posted, and then type mydata and compare it to the printed data.frame you posted. They don't match up. Element 7 in the example data is `D-1`, not `A101`

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Oh my fault, you are right ...but it seems that I have problem with lapply ....see edits...

Comment: @JohnC -- eusebe's code has an error in it. Replace his/her definition of `dup` with `dup <- unique(mydata$subject[duplicated(mydata$subject)])` (i.e. wrapping the RHS with `unique()`) to get the correct results.

Comment: @JohnC -- If that works for you, you might consider editing eusebe's answer to add the missing `unique()` and then accepting it. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different approach. First split apart all the data by subject, and then keep only the ones that have more than one entry.

```
sets <- split(mydata, mydata$subject)
Filter(function(x) {nrow(x)>1}, sets)
```

If you don't need the intermediate, it can be inlined.

```
Filter(function(x) {nrow(x)>1}, split(mydata, mydata$subject))
```

which gives

```
> Filter(function(x) {nrow(x)>1}, split(mydata, mydata$subject))
$`A-B10`
  sn subject idn
1  1   A-B10 101
3  3   A-B10 104

$A101
  sn subject idn
2  2    A101 102
5  5    A101  98
7  7    A101  90
```